# How to create form type when using groups in FOSUserbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'd like to use groups in FOSUserbundle, so I have entity User related to Entity Group as it is indicated in the documentation.

If for example I have 3 groups and each group has **different attributes**, my question is ,  how to create the **formType of each group** ? shall I create a formType for each one or what ?

Comment: I suggest you consider [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle).  It is designed to address the case of different types of users, which appears to be your use case.

Comment: @geoB : But if we can't do this with FOSUserbundle so what's the role of Groups in this bundle ??

Comment: From the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/groups.html): "Groups are a way to group a collection of roles."  If your users vary only in role (i.e., level of security) then Groups is fine.  If instead they vary by other properties then PUGXMultiUser may be appropriate.  An example: my application has volunteers with both focus & skill attributes, admin has neither, staff has an organization with focus attributes.  This cannot be done with Groups.